# Weird behavior of javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please see attached screenshot. See pendingApp property of Object. when I am debugging in eclipse then pendingApp show array of object, Which is correct! But when I am `JSON.stringify(object)` then showing me empty Array.
[image: Eclipse Image]

[image: Terminal Image]

Please let me know reason of this behavior. I think I am not aware with any Java-Script thought/concept  ?? :P :)

**When I will save this Object into DB then blank array of pendingApp will be stored !!**

```
var pending_app = [];
var new_record = {"pendingApp" : [], "installedApp" :[] };
....SOME CODE+conditions HERE....
 pending_app[appId] = {'action' : action };
 new_record.pendingApp = pending_app;
// create app-config data
 return app_model.create(new_record); //will return promise object
```

Comment: You object might not be stringifyable

Comment: Its just manually created javascript object and why not save it into DB ???

Comment: Wait for your array to get filled. You use some asynchronous functions, don't you?

Comment: @Bergi : Please mention link.

Comment: @ManishTrivedi: Please mention code.

Comment: But see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function. The question I've closed as a duplicate of explains what you are seeing in the debugger.

Comment: @ Bergi : I got your point but why is it not storing into my db ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86970/discussion-between-manish-trivedi-and-bergi).

Comment: @ManishTrivedi , the variable `appId ` might not be a number, then `JSON.stringify` return empty array repr (as I said in my first comment)

Comment: @Hacketo : May be You are right!! its sting-stingrValue kind of value. But JSON.stringify print it always.  ( According to my past logs)

Comment: When I will create  ` var new_record = {"pendingApp" : {}, "installedApp" :{} }; ` then issue is resolved.

Comment: @Hacketo: Wanna make that an answer?

Comment: @Bergi I will, not able to do it right now, android app seem buggy

Comment: Need to see what you have done in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a weird behaviour but a common mistake of using an `Array` to store key-value data.

**Short Answer :** Use a literal Object to store these data

---

While you can add properties on every objects in Javascript, you cannot iterate over them with the default array mechanisms

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){}
array.forEach();
```

**Simple demonstration :**

```js
var array = [];
array["anId"] = 1;
array.length; // 0

array[4294967295] = 1; // Indice >= unsigned 32-bit Max Value
array.length; // 0
array[4294967295]; // 1
```

---

So [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) with the [ECMAScript 5 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3) will use the `Array` mechanism to iterate over all items and will find nothing.

Unlike `Objects` that you can list properties with

```
Object.keys(array); // ["anId"]
```